# Is there a way to pass a Java class to new file within Eclipse?

Tags: java, class, oop

I'm a new programmer, so please be patient with me!

I have two files created: `tableBlocks.java` and `buildBuffer.java`. 
Within the file tableBlocks, I read in a file, perform some mathematical operations (not shown below), and insert the results into a byte array.
Within the file buildBuffer, I build an empty buffer (another array).

I want to be able to insert the built byte array from `tableBlocks` into the buffer array located in `buildBuffer`. However, I haven't been able to pass information between files.

I tried the extend and implement methods, neither with any luck. Inserting into an array is difficult enough in Java (apparently).

> Table7Block2.java

```
public final class Table7Block2 {
    private static final String INPUT_FILE_NAME = "C:\\Users\\CASPERLS\\BinaryData.bin";
    private static final String OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "C:\\Users\\CASPERLS\\BinaryWritten.bin";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Table7Block2 test = new Table7Block2();
        byte[] fileContents = test.read(INPUT_FILE_NAME); // create empty array
        test.write(fileContents, OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
    }
}
```

> buildBuffer.java

```
public class buildBuffer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytebuf = new byte[236];
        int position, n, value;
        n = 235;
        position = 11;
        value = 1;
        int c;
        for (c = n - 1; c >= position - 1; c--) {
            bytebuf[c + 1] = bytebuf[c];
        }
        bytebuf[position] = (byte) value;

        System.out.println("Resultant array is");

        for (c = 0; c <= n; c++) {
            System.out.print(bytebuf[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call "bytebuf" in my TableBlock code, and insert the data I read in from the random file into my bytebuf array.

Comment: You only need one main method and for passing array you can do that via method or constructor.

Comment: I only need one main even though it's two separate files?

Comment: Yes. You initialize other file from main by creating it's object. For Example `buildBuffer bB = new buildBuffer();` This line will call the constructor in class buildBuffer and through that object you can call methods in that class.